# How do I change the canvas size of a PNG with ImageMagick (GraphicsMagick)? (How to pad with transparency?)

Tags: images, graphics, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

Alternatively: How do I take a non-square PNG and "fill out" the "rest" of the image with transparency so that the resulting square image has the original image centered in the square?

ULTIMATELY, what I want is to take any image of any GM-supported format of any size, and create a scaled-down PNG (say, 40 pixels maximum for either dimension), with aspect ratio maintained, transparency-padded for non-square original images, AND with an already-prepared 40x40 PNG transparency mask applied.

I already know how to scale down and keep aspect ratio; I already have the command for applying my composite.  My only missing piece is square-alizing non-square images (padding with transparency).

Single command preferred; multi-command chain acceptable.

(edit)

Extra info: Here's the composite command I'm using:

```
gm composite -compose copyopacity mask.png source-and-target.png source-and-target.png
```

where mask.png has white pixels for what I want to keep of source-and-target.png and transparent pixels for what I want to remove (and become transparent) of source-and-target.png.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This command will take any sized input file and fit it best to a 40x40 square and pad with transparency:

```
convert \
   original.png \
  -thumbnail '40x40>' \
  -background transparent \
  -gravity center \
  -extent 40x40 \
  -compose Copy_Opacity \
  -composite mask.png \
   original-resized.png
```

The `gravity` option ensures the image is centered in both directions, and `transparent` is used wherever there are no pixels.  Then the compositing is done with the `mask.png`

Comment: So we can't do it in one shot with ```composite```?

Comment: @Pistos I am not clear on what you are doing with the composite - it is just a transparency mask to hide/show portions of the thumbnail after resizing?  Can you [edit] and add the command sequence you have so far, so we can see if it can be combined?

Comment: @Pistos I think the best approach is to do the compositing with -convert rather than the other way around.  I have updated my answer above.

Comment: Close, but not quite.  Your command didn't work as-is, and even with adjustments, it didn't work.  It's okay, I'll do it in two steps.  I'll update things here after I get the final, working CLI steps.  Thanks again.

Comment: I would add `-filter Catrom` before the `thumbnail` option because from my experience it generally produces higher quality images.

Answer (score 9):

One command to convert all PNGs from one folder:

```
mogrify \
 -resize 50x50 \
 -background transparent \
 -gravity center \
 -extent 50x50 \
 -format png \
 -path resized \
 *.png
```

*mogrify* is a command from ImageMagick package. You have to create output directory first.

Comment: Nice one. BTW, If you feel adventurous, you can omit `-path resized` to edit the files in place.

Comment: This is great. On my install (OSX, 1.3.35) it's `gm mogrify` and instead of `-path resized`, use `-create-directories -output-directory resized`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I eventually went with.  A two step process:

```
gm convert \
  -thumbnail '40x40>' \
  -background transparent \
  -gravity center \
  -extent 40x40 \
   original.png \
   intermediate.png

gm composite \
  -compose in \
   intermediate.png \
   mask.png \
   out.png
```

Where mask.png is white pixels for what I wanted to keep, and transparent pixels for what I wanted to mask out (discard).